# Odd behavior with <allow users="*" /> pages

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a page in a forms authentication site that I added  in the web.config that, every once in a while, redirect to the login page anyways. I have error handles set up everywhere on the page in question, and no errors occur, it just gets redirected to the login page. Below is the web.config code to allow the page through forms authentication. Has anyone seen this before, or have an suggestions on why this may be happening.

```
<location path="lflookup.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the event logs for some more info.  Also check your session timeout to see if that is why it is doing the redirect.

Comment: Yeah, I'd check the event logs. You might want to look at the AppPool settings for the project.

Comment: The event logs show the session is timing out after 20min, but nothing else related to IIS or the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change the * to a ? - this will allow anonymous users. See if the redirct to the login page occurs then.

Comment: I believe the ? actually makes it so a valid session is required, and will force a redirect to the login page if login wasn't completed prior to navigating to the page.... at least that's how this one is working.